# React typescript with axios response type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm building a sample web app and using [this](https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products) dummy data api to fetch data. I'm using React with axios to make the api call.The response data looks like following

[image: api data looks like]

So I created following interfaces to represent the data.

```
export type Category = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

export type Product = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    image: string,
    price: number,
    discount_amount: number,
    status: boolean,
    categories: Array<Category>
}
export type ProductResponse = {
    data: {
        code: number,
        data: Array<Product>
    }
}
```

I'm tying to fetch data and store in a typed state variable following way

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<Product>>([]);

  const fetchProducts = (): void => {
    const productUrl = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
    axios.get<ProductResponse>(productUrl).then((res) => {
      setProducts(res.data.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
```

There is a type error

```
/home/ravinda/myjunkbox/react/react-redux-cake-shop-ts/src/components/Products.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/ravinda/myjunkbox/react/react-redux-cake-shop-ts/src/components/Products.tsx(12,19):
Argument of type '{ code: number; data: Product[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Product[]>'.
  Type '{ code: number; data: Product[]; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Product[]) => Product[]'.
    Type '{ code: number; data: Product[]; }' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Product[]): Product[]'.  TS2345

    10 |     const productUrl = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
    11 |     axios.get<ProductResponse>(productUrl).then((res) => {
  > 12 |       setProducts(res.data.data);
       |                   ^
    13 |     });
    14 |   };
    15 |
```

I think I'm trying to extract the product array out of the response and set to the state variable. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error given, I believe you're lacking an extra `.data` on your result. In order to access the value within Axios's [response](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/f472e5da5fe76c72db703d6a0f5190e4ad31e642/index.d.ts#L77), you need to do a `.data`, in your case, `.data` will give you `ProductResponse`.

```
const fetchProducts = (): void => {
    const productUrl = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
    axios.get<ProductResponse>(productUrl).then((res) => {
      setProducts(res.data.data.data);
    });
  };
```

`res.data` should give you `ProductResponse`

`res.data.data` should give you

```
{
  code: number,
  data: Array<Product>
}
```

`res.data.data.data` should give you `Array<Product>`, the same type you specified in your `useState`.